# UIView Shadow using BezierPath massively offsets the shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadow

I've added a shadow to a UIView, but get the following result:

[image]

The code is the following:

```
mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
mainView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
mainView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
mainView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
mainView.clipsToBounds = false
mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
mainView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: mainView.frame, cornerRadius: 8).cgPath
```

Given that I gave the shadowPath the exact frame as the blue view (mainView), I don't understand why the shadow is so offset. I understand that I can potentially fix this using the shadowOffset property, but the whole reason I'm trying to use shadowPath instead is to *not* use shadowOffset given that it potentially has some performance issues at scale.

Update: After fixing mainView.frame to mainView.bounds, the shadow is appropriately aligned. However, the shadow seems to still be slightly offset at the top of the mainView (having a stronger shadow above):

[image]

Comment: try changing mainView.frame to mainView.bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the shadow is specified in the coordinates of the view, therefore you should be using `mainView.bounds`.

```
mainView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: mainView.bounds, cornerRadius: 8).cgPath
```

In other words, you want a rectangle with origin `(0, 0)`, not with the position of `mainView`.

Comment: Didn't realize that it gets specified in terms of the view's coordinates! Thank you.

Comment: after your fix, do you know why the shadow may be stronger above the UIView than below (updated my original question with a screenshot)? I would have expected an even distribution of the shadow.

Comment: @pizza7 the only idea I have is that your view height got increased. Are you updating the shadow when the size changes? E.g. in `layoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 0):

> the shadow seems to still be slightly offset at the top of the mainView

This is because `shadowOffset` has a default value `(0.0, -3.0)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410970-shadowoffset

To avoid this, you can use `offsetBy`

`mainView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: mainView.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: 3.0), cornerRadius: 8).cgPath`

or simply, pass `.zero` to `shadowOffset`

`mainView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero`